# Where is the full narrators for the narration that says that Jesus (AS) will die in later days?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, authenticity, uloom-al-hadith, ilm-ar-rijal

I need the full chain of narrators for the following narration:-

It is narrated from Ibn Abbas about the Ayah “I’ll take you and raise you”; “It means I’ll raise you then will cause you to die near the End of Times.

Comment: Could you provide the exact wording of the hadith

Comment: @ahmadbutt - Here is the text in Arabic:- 

عن ابن عباس في قوله { إني متوفيك ورافعك } يعني رافعك ثم متوفيك في آخر الزمان

Comment: @ahmadbutt - It will be very helpful if you can provide complete chain of narrators for this narration.